# How many book hours to replace the roller cam in 1999 Chevrolet

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, camshaft, book-hours

How many book hours to replace the roller cam in 1999 Chevrolet Silverado with 5.7L auto, power steering air condition

Butch

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Should be pretty standard for any SBC like in your Silvy. Someone should be able to give you the answer, but ... not me, lol.

Comment: I don't have a labor guide but I would guess 5-6 hours at least.

Answer (score 2):

Local shop provided answer today   His book indicated 13.8 hours